# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 error in mapreduce, Hadoop

Tags: java, apache, csv, hadoop, bigdata

I was trying to solve this question using hadoop.

Find the top ten rated businesses using the average ratings. Top rated business will come first. Recall that 4th column in review.csv file represents the rating.

My java code is:

```
package bd;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


    public class TopTenRatedBusiness {

        /*
         * Mapper Class : BusinessRatingMapper
         * Class BusinessRatingMapper parses review.csv file and emits business id and respective rating
         */
        public static class BusinessRatingMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, FloatWritable> {
            /*
             * Map function that emits a business ID as a key and rating as a value
             */
            @Override
            protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                String reviews[] = value.toString().split("::");
                /*
                 * reviews[2] gives business id and reviews[3] gives business rating
                 */
                context.write(new Text(reviews[2]), new FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat(reviews[3])));

            }
        } 

        /*
         * Reducer class: TopRatedBusinessReducer
         * Class TopRatedBusinessReducer emits top 10 business id with their average rating
         */
        static TreeMap<Float, List<Text>> reviewID = new TreeMap<Float, List<Text>>(Collections.reverseOrder());

        public static class BusinessRatingReducer extends Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, FloatWritable> {

            /*
             * Reduce function
             */
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                float sumOfRatings =  0;
                int countOfRatings = 0;
                for (FloatWritable value : values) {
                    sumOfRatings += value.get();
                    countOfRatings++; 
                }

                Float averageRating = sumOfRatings / countOfRatings;

                if (reviewID.containsKey(averageRating)) {
                    reviewID.get(averageRating).add(new Text(key.toString()));
                } else {
                    List<Text> businessIDList = new ArrayList<Text>();
                    businessIDList.add(new Text(key.toString()));

                    /*
                     * Putting average rating and corresponding business ID
                     */
                    reviewID.put(averageRating, businessIDList);
                }
            }


            @Override
            protected void cleanup(Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, FloatWritable>.Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                int count=0;
                for(Entry<Float, List<Text>> entry : reviewID.entrySet()) {
                    if(count > 10){
                        break;
                    }

                 FloatWritable result=new FloatWritable();
                 result.set(entry.getKey());

                 for (int i = 0; i <entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                      if (count >= 10) {
                            break;
                      }
                       context.write(new Text(entry.getValue().get(i).toString()), result);
                       count++;
                  }

                }  

            }
        }

            /*
             * Driver Program
             */

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException, NoSuchMethodException {

                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
                if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
                    System.err.println("Usage: TopTenRatedBusiness <in> <out>");
                    System.exit(2);

                }
                /*
                 * Create a job with name "TopTenRatedBusiness"
                 */

                Job job = new Job(conf, "TopTenRatedBusiness");
                job.setJarByClass(TopTenRatedBusiness.class);

                job.setMapperClass(BusinessRatingMapper.class);
                job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setMapOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

                job.setReducerClass(BusinessRatingReducer.class);
                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

        }

}
```

My dataset:

review.csv file contains the star rating given by a user to a business. Use user_id to associate this review with others by the same user. Use business_id to associate this review with others of the same business.

```
review.csv file contains the following columns "review_id"::"user_id"::"business_id"::"stars" 
'review_id': (a unique identifier for the review) 
'user_id': (the identifier of the reviewed business), 
'business_id': (the identifier of the authoring user), 
'stars': (star rating, integer 1-5),the rating given by the user to a business
```

I am getting the following error when i run this:

```
17/10/09 21:18:33 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/10/09 21:18:33 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
17/10/09 21:18:33 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
17/10/09 21:18:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201710090351_0033
17/10/09 21:18:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/10/09 21:18:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201710090351_0033_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:37)
    at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:26)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

17/10/09 21:18:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201710090351_0033_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:37)
    at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:26)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

17/10/09 21:18:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201710090351_0033_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:37)
    at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:26)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201710090351_0033
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=23391
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
17/10/09 21:18:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
```

Few sample input lines

```
0xuZfa0t4MNWd3eIFF02ug::kT43SxDgMGzbeXpO51f0hQ::wbpbaWBfU54JbjLIDwERQA::5.0
bBqVqhOvNgFs8I1Wk68QUQ::T9hGHsbJW9Hw1cJAlIAWmw::4iTRjN_uAdAb7_YZDVHJdg::5.0
fu7TcxnAOdnbdLcyFhMmZg::Z_WAxc4RUpKp3y12BH1bEg::qw5gR8vW7mSOK4VROSwdMA::4.0
LMy8UOKOeh0b9qrz-s1fQA::OlMjqqzWZUv2-62CSqKq_A::81IjU5L-t-QQwsE38C63hQ::4.0
JjyRj9EiBXQTFDQAxRtt4g::fs5bpfk-2pvq2v8S1De5pQ::Hnz1_h_D1eHSRtQqHSCZkw::2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for the sample input.

So it looks to be an issue with your data, where there will be erroneous rows which are unable to process. You can check for if there are any header columns or you will need to go through the full file.

Another thing you can check is the input directory path you are providing is having the only review.CSV file and nothing else.

Comment: there are no headers. can you further guide me?

Comment: I googled it out and found out that https://github.com/patilankita79/Analysis-of-Yelp-Dataset-Using-Pig-Latin, is this the input file you are trying to run? (review.csv)

Comment: I ran the review.csv with the code you have written and I am able to run it successfully. What is the structure of your input path? Input path directory should contain only review.csv file.

Comment: okay. review.csv is in my hadoop file system along with some other csv files. So, should only 1 input file be present in that particular directory?

Comment: exactly only files of one type should exist in your directory. i.e. you can have multiple review.csv, review1.csv, review2.csv files with different data sets. If you have different types of input files in the input path, MR job will fail to process it properly.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Comment: I am still getting the same error. what platform did you use to run this?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:37)
 at bd.TopTenRatedBusiness$BusinessRatingMapper.map(TopTenRatedBusiness.java:26)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: I am running this on linux box. If you are still seeing the error, I would recommend you to download new dataset review.csv from the above link, put it in a completely different directory and run MR job again providing it as an input Path. It looks like the input file is not correct.

Comment: I think that there was some issue with the input file only. It works fine now. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

This line gives you an error

```
context.write(new Text(reviews[2]), new FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat(reviews[3])));
```

Try to use debugger to fix this

Comment: Can you please suggest the changes?

Comment: I am new to hadoop

Comment: Did you get the solution to this issue. I seem to be stuck because of the same issue.